# Playing Audio from UDP received message, Clicking sound (Naudio API)

Tags: c#, udp, naudio

I'm creating a chat client that has UDP for voice chat, but when I send the audio (in bytes) to the other clients, the client plays the audio everything is clear but I hear a random clicking sound in the back ground. I thought it might be because it's UDP and not checking if the data is correct, but no. Even when I send through TCP I can still hear the clicking sound in the background.

CODE to recreate:

```
using NAudio.Wave;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace QuestionStack
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        UdpClient UDPc;
        private NAudio.Wave.WaveIn sourceStream;
        IPEndPoint ep;//where the client will send the udp data from recording
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// client clicks when he wants to start connection with other client
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void StartAudioButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UDPc = new UdpClient(Int32.Parse(MyPortTextBox.Text));
            ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), Int32.Parse(OtherUserTextBoxPort.Text)); // endpoint where other clienr is listening
            UDPc.Connect(ep);
            UDPc.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveUdpMessage), null);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            StartAudioRecording();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// where the client takes the audio in bytes, he got from otehr client to convert and play the audio 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ar"></param>
        private void ReceiveUdpMessage(IAsyncResult ar)
        {

            try
            {
                byte[] bytesRead = UDPc.EndReceive(ar, ref ep);

                BufferedWaveProvider provider = new BufferedWaveProvider(new WaveFormat(44100, 16, 2));
                provider.DiscardOnBufferOverflow = true;
                provider.AddSamples(bytesRead, 0, bytesRead.Length);
                DirectSoundOut _waveOut = new DirectSoundOut();
                _waveOut.Init(provider);
                _waveOut.Play();

                UDPc.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveUdpMessage), null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// starts recording and sents to other client if check box to only listen is not on
        /// </summary>
        public void StartAudioRecording()
        {
            if (!checkBoxOnlyListen.Checked)
            {
                sourceStream = new NAudio.Wave.WaveIn();
                sourceStream.DeviceNumber = 0;
                sourceStream.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(44100, NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.GetCapabilities(0).Channels);


                sourceStream.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs>(sourceStream_DataAvailable);

                sourceStream.StartRecording();
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// if got recording, sends it to other client
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void sourceStream_DataAvailable(object sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sourceStream == null) return;
            try
            {
                UDPc.Send(e.Buffer, e.BytesRecorded);//sending data UPD
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

[FormsPicture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfeJo.png)
So if the data is ok, the way I'm translating and playing it is causing the problems.
I checked, it doesn't matter if the Wave out object is created outside of the method.
I tried a million different ways to fix it. I have no idea how to. If anyone knows a better way to translate or fix it, It would make my week.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.

Comment: 44Khz PCM is crazy big to be streaming without compression. It's probably just latency (network not keeping up with realtime). If you save to disk instead and then play it back later, it would probably sound fine.

Comment: But, if  you save to disk wont it cause High latency (I want it to be a live voice chat like discord) and even when I lower the PCM to 11k it still makes clicks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a single output device and a single `BufferedWaveProvider`, and start playing before you receive any audio. Then in the receive function, the only thing you need to do is add received audio to the `BufferedWaveProvider`. However, you will still get clicks if the audio is not being received fast enough over the network which will mean you have dropouts in the received audio.

Comment: Thank you, for the answer and API